# Alternatives to Remote Blob Storage for O365

Tags: document-library, document, remote-blob-storage, rbs, hybrid-solution

Anyone have any thoughts/suggestions:

Currently Remote Blob Storage is not available in SharePoint Online / O365.  We have some remote locations in other countries where documents must stay within the country. However we would like to make the front end be available in SharePoint Online.

We may use local SharePoint farms in those locations in a hybrid scenario, but would like to understand alternatives (local file shares, 3rd party tools, etc).  The key is documents MUST remain within the boundaries of the local environment.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility for any kind of custom Remote Blob Storage for Office 365. You must use an on-premises service such as SharePoint 2013 or file shares locally.

You could build a SharePoint App that Surfaces the data/links to your on-premises data.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it was available in the online versions, Remote Blob Storage would just offload the files to the file system of the SharePoint servers (or wherever MS would deem appropriate), not keep them locally.

In conjunction Wictor's suggestion, you could also try to use a Page Viewer web part and point it to the local file share. This will surface the files for use from the network location in an iframe, they are never physically in the SharePoint environment.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this a late response, but I thought it would be useful to anyone who lands here in the future.

Microsoft released Multi-Geo for SharePoint online in 2019.  I think that this is probably the best solution this problem.  For more information check out: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/multi-geo-capabilities-in-onedrive-and-sharepoint-online-in-office-365

Keep in mind that Multi-Geo is limited to customers with more than 2,500 Office 365 subscriptions.